# Locking tables/projections while creating design

Tags: logging, locking, projection, vertica

I have a question about locking tables/queries.

1. Does Vertica lock some tables or projections during process of designing new projections (programatically or with DBDesigner in Admintools)? Here I mean the tables/projections which are involved in new design. I have a suspicion that during the process of designing the original tables/projections must be in consistent state, so the content of tables/projection is during the design the same all the time (it means that the tables/projections are read-only). The problem is that it isn't possible to write to the database during the time of designing.
2. Is there any way to observe it in log files? I went through vertica.log but there was nothing about locking tables/projections.
3. Is there any way to get round the locking? I would like to work normally (write, update) with database also during the process of designing.

I hope that the questions are clear. If not, I specify it more.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding. I would still test first, but based on my observations...

1. Only the target projection gets an `X` lock. The table (and other projections) should be available for other DML operations.
2. Any locks would be seen in the `locks` and `lock_usage` system views. I don't think you'll see this in the log (although perhaps there is a logging option to enable that level of detail, might need to ask support).
3. Since it doesn't lock, you should be fine. However, if I'm wrong and issues do arise, you'd have to copy the table, add the new projections, refresh, then `ALTER TABLE T1, T2, temps RENAME TO temps, T1, T2;` to swap them. Then DML to update any changes you made to the data during this time.

Now what it will do is slow down the projection refresh significantly if you are inserting while refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

If the database designer is run with the Incremental Design option then additional projections are created.
However, if the database designer is run with the Comprehensive Design option then the unrequired projections are dropped and old projections are replaced by new projections.

In both these cases there is no lock performed on tables as the database designer initiates a new session and a separate workspace is created. In this workspace the data is analyzed to come up with appropriate
encoding and compression required for a column to improve projection performance in the database.

You can check the Database designer log at the path
`/home/dbadmin/designer.log`

```
2016-11-30 05:26:05 [Designer.sendCommand] Executing: select dbd_create_workspace('tet1',True);
2016-11-30 05:26:05 [Designer.sendCommand] Status: 0. Result: ['0']
2016-11-30 05:26:05 [Designer.send_sql_text] Sending SQL: select dbd_create_design('tet1','tet1');
select dbd_set_design_ksafety('tet1','tet1','0');
select dbd_set_optimization_objective('tet1','tet1','Load');
2016-11-30 05:26:05 [Designer.sendCommand] Sending commands in /home/dbadmin//command.sql
2016-11-30 05:26:05 Setting search path: SET search_path=sid,public;
2016-11-30 05:26:05 [Designer.sendCommand] Executing: select dbd_create_design('tet1','tet1');
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.sendCommand] Status: 0. Result: ['0']
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.sendCommand] Executing: select dbd_set_design_ksafety('tet1','tet1','0');
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.sendCommand] Status: 0. Result: ['0']
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.sendCommand] Executing: select dbd_set_optimization_objective('tet1','tet1','Load');
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.sendCommand] Status: 0. Result: ['0']
2016-11-30 05:26:06 Design schemas are: sid
2016-11-30 05:26:06 [Designer.send_sql_text] Sending SQL: select dbd_add_design_tables('tet1','sid.*');
2016-11-30 05:26:07 Examining table data...
2016-11-30 05:26:07 [Designer.fPrint] Output: 
    Examining table data..
```

.

Comment: Formatting required.